# Unable to understand this mysql deadlock log

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7, deadlock

I am getting a good number of these deadlocks (low % of total requests, but still high in absolute errors). For all the deadlocks, the pattern is very similar; but I am unable to understand why there is a deadlock

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2020-02-05 03:52:47 0x2b38b7b91700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 257063481717, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 4990288, OS thread handle 47474114635520, query id 359069256602 172.26.107.139 update
INSERT INTO `message_user_records` (`message_template_id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `expires_at`, `token`) VALUES (1294, 26396574, '2020-02-05 03:52:47', '2020-02-05 03:52:47', '2020-02-05 10:52:47', 'XTBLUQXF2GVPW') 
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 676 page no 548680 n bits 1120 index index_message_user_records_on_user_id_and_dismissed of table `ebdb`.`message_user_records` trx id 257063481717 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 124 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 8192c7a2; asc     ;;
 1: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 2: len 4; hex 83fc1ead; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 257063481715, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 5000
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 4991120, OS thread handle 47522600523520, query id 359069256588 172.26.144.135 update
INSERT INTO `message_user_records` (`message_template_id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `expires_at`, `token`) VALUES (1294, 26396574, '2020-02-05 03:52:47', '2020-02-05 03:52:47', '2020-02-05 10:52:47', 'QA4DL6VSMTWR4')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 676 page no 548680 n bits 1120 index index_message_user_records_on_user_id_and_dismissed of table `ebdb`.`message_user_records` trx id 257063481715 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 124 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 8192c7a2; asc     ;;
 1: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 2: len 4; hex 83fc1ead; asc     ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 676 page no 548680 n bits 1120 index index_message_user_records_on_user_id_and_dismissed of table `ebdb`.`message_user_records` trx id 257063481715 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 124 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 8192c7a2; asc     ;;
 1: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 2: len 4; hex 83fc1ead; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

If I am understanding correctly, txn2 holds the lock that txn1 is waiting for. But the lock that txn2 is waiting for seems to be the same one it already holds. What am I missing here?

For context on the application code, it seems to be doing these statements -

```
BEGIN;
SELECT `message_user_records`.* FROM `message_user_records` WHERE `message_user_records`.`user_id` = <some-id> AND `message_user_records`.`message_template_id` = <some-another-id> FOR UPDATE;

...

INSERT INTO `message_user_records` (`message_template_id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `expires_at`, `token`) VALUES (list of values with same ids as above select) 
COMMIT
```

#### Edit

Here's the table description

```
CREATE TABLE `message_user_records` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_template_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dismissed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `input` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `expires_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_rating` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `option_1` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `option_2` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `option_3` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `option_4` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `option_5` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `option_6` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_message_user_records_on_token` (`token`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_message_user_records_on_message_template_id` (`message_template_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_message_user_records_on_user_id_and_dismissed` (`user_id`,`dismissed`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE message_user_records\G`?

Comment: The error message show two transactions are inserting the same row with only the `token` value different.  Given the token isn't the primary/unique key you'll need to answer why this happens.

Comment: @danblack - how do we know that the `token` value isn't part of a PK/UQK? - That's why I asked for the structure of the table!

Comment: Hi @Vérace and @danblack, thank you checking and responding. Updated with table description, `token` is a unique key on the table. Still dont follow what the second txn is waiting on. Thanks again!

Comment: Quite right - comments about token being a unique key where in the wrong direction. They values are different so it doesn't matter that there is a unique key. @Rahul is important to differentiate the difference between a deadlock, two concurrent updates of the same row, and a lock wait, and update that depends on reading data that another transaction is updating. I'm currently missing why this is a deadlock, it's probably related to the only index that SELECT .. FOR UPDATE can use. Are the two inserts that deadlocked actually valid in a business sense (same data except for the token)?

Comment: The two concurrent inserts are definitely invalid in business logic sense and ideally shouldn't trigger. I am trying to debug why is that even happening with the owners of that code. But yes, separately, couldn't understand the mysql deadlock log.

Answer (score 1):

**Understanding** -- I can't explain the details, but I think this is the big clue:  "lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert".

**Avoiding**

Are there other statements in each transaction?  They may have impact.

The two `INSERTs` are hitting the same pair of columns that you are `SELECTing FOR UPDATE`:  (1294, 26396574)

You are only providing a *conflicting* `token` for that pair.

Please explain the business logic that calls for two different tokens.

You could *try* replacing the `KEY(message_template_id)` with `INDEX(message_template_id, user_id)`.  It would potentially make the `SELECT` run faster.  That *might* help the transactions get finished faster, hence diminishing the frequency of, but not eliminating, deadlocks.

A more likely solution is to stretch the index further, into

```
INDEX(message_template_id, user_id, token)
```

This *may* eliminate the deadlock, perhaps by turning it into a "lock wait timeout".

But, in *any* case, you should plan on getting deadlocks, test for them in your code, and have the code re-play the transaction.